# How to use lookbehind or lookahead and replace the matched string?

Tags: regex, lookbehind

I am stuck at one more RegEx.

Sample input :

```
project description
```

I want to write RegEx. that if word "description" is found and its preceded by word "project" then prepend "project description" with "<project>".

expected output :

```
<project>project description
```

I wrote following Regex, n replacement string but its not working :
regex : `((?<=project) description)`
and replacement string : `<project_description>$0`

With current regex and replacement string im getting following output :

```
project<project> description
```

Can anyone suggest something?

---

**

> EDITED QUESTION

** 
Ok, I think I am not clear enough about telling people what I want exactly.

To make the problem generic and clearer, I will put it in another way.

If "y" comes after "x", then prepend `<tag>` to xy.

Is it possible to do this using regular expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED ANSWER:

This doesn't seem appropriate for lookbehind. Why don't you just replace the whole thing, like this:

```
s/(project|other|word) description/<project>$1 description/
```

This will prepend the word `<project>` to any of `project`, `other`, or `word` if it is followed by `description`.

Comment: Actually, the text that i have given in question is just a sample text. Actually text might be any of the following forms: 1) Details of project or 2) project(s) summary or 3) project or 4) projects undertaken. For all the above i want to prepend <project> to those words.

Comment: Edit the question and add these conditions.

Comment: @Amarghosh,
It is not possible to provide all the possibilites of text that will occure in file because even I dont know what will occur in later stages.
To make the problem generic and clearer, I will put it in another way
If "y" comes after "x", then prepend <t> to xy.
Is it possible to do this using regular expressions?

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand why you're using a lookbehind for this - you can just do:

```
/project description/  ->  <project>$0
```

In PHP this would be

```
echo preg_replace('/project description/', '<project>$0', $str);
```

Comment: Hi Greg, the text that i have given in question is just a sample text. Actually text might be any of the following forms: 1) Details of project or 2) project(s) summary or 3) project or 4) projects undertaken. For all the above i want to prepend <project> to those words.

Answer (score 2):

Extending Greg's regex to match the newly added cases:

```
/Details\sof\sproject|project(\sdescription|s\sundertaken|\(s\)\ssummary)/

//replace all the matches with

<project>$0
```

You can later add new cases to this regex using `|`.

---

EDIT: To answer `If "y" comes after "x", then prepend <tag> to xy.`

> Replace `/x\s\y/` with `<tag>$0`

This will prepent `<tag>` to all occurrences of x-space-y